# Filestream column in the WHERE clause locks the server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, filestream

I have implemented filestream in an existing database on SQL Server 2008 r2.

Now I have a very urgent problem as my site is practically down now:

With a very simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [Image] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [Table1RowguidUnique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [rowguid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_table1_rowguid]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [rowguid]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
SET ( FILESTREAM_ON = fsfg_LiveWebsite )
GO
```

If I run:

```
select * from Table1 where Id = 1
```

it runs very quickly and give the correct result.
If I run anything with the "Varbinary(max) FILESTREAM" field in the where clause the whole table locks down.
So for example any of those 2 queries:

```
select Id from Table1 where Id = 1 and [Image] is null
select Id from Table1 where Id = 1 and [Image] = convert(varbinary(max), 'a')
```

What could this be?

Please reply asap with any suggestion!

Thank you

Comment: If you look in `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` whilst it is blocked what is the wait type and resource?

Comment: Did you test this before implementing it on your site? Also I suggest you update the terminology of your question - that is a `VARBINARY` column, not a filestream column.

Comment: @MartinSmith the dm_os_waiting_tasks and the wait type change continuosly if I query it again while it is executing. Those are the values that they assume: PREEMPTIVE_OS_GETFILESIZE,0/PREEMPTIVE_OS_FILEOPS,0/PREEMPTIVE_OS_CREATEFILE,2/(no results)/PREEMPTIVE_OS_CLOSEHANDLE,0

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me that it should be able to access the column to output its value when doing a `SELECT *` but not when filtering by it. Is that definitely correct? Also how do the execution plans compare and what about @AaronBertrand's comment above? You seem to be missing any mention of `FILESTREAM` in the table definition. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: I suspect the first (fast) query is actually `select Id` not `select *`...

Comment: @MartinSmith I checked again and it is definitely correct. select * gives the result in no time. The table definition is taken from the context menu "script table as"-"Create to". Apparently the filestream part is not added to that script. I will update the post to add the instructions I used to create the filestream

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can confirm that the query is select *. I also tried select [Image] .. and it works fine. I am updating the text in consideration of your suggestion of wording too.

Comment: @Durden81 - What about the execution plans? Hopefully something obvious there or I've no idea.

Comment: @MartinSmith I changed the code with the Filestream information. Any idea?

Comment: The estimated execution plan didn't show anything interesting (it said that 100% of the work was for the Pk_Table1. To find the correct Id). Now it started working again without any change at all! I hope it lasts. This seems like a bug to me. I think I would change all the queries in my site to NEVER use the condition "is null" on a filestream field. I would add a bit field and set it to 1 every time there is a null value. should I put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost if you want to query a VARBINARY column you'll need to enable and use Full-Text Search.

Reference Articles.

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142531.aspx (this article will give you an overview of Full-Text Search and the VARBINARY column)
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx (this article will show you how to use the CONTAINS T-SQL command to query the field)

Comment: before I implemented filestream it was working fine. the only where clause I need it's the "is null" one. I don't need any other function that is given by full-text search. Also I always specify a unique id too, so it only has to check a single varbinary(max). From what I read your articles don't say that enabling full-text search is necessary or that it would improve my situation.

Comment: Have you verified the execution plan?  I believe -- without setting up your environment -- a scan is occurring because the VARBINARY is not indexed and thus making the unique id irrelevant.  And so now that scan is on the file system.

Comment: The estimated execution plan didn't show anything interesting (it said that 100% of the work was for the Pk_Table1. To find the correct Id). However the issue seems that it fixed by itself for now.